# Setting environment variable for a different user in windows

Tags: windows, environment-variables

There are tons of examples on the web how to set an [environment variable for the current user](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/121664-set-new-user-system-environment-variables-windows.html). Is it possible to set an environment variable in windows for a different user (that does not have login rights?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the registry editor `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is just an alias for the `HKEY_USERS\$SID` entry of the current user.

So, you only need to go to `HKEY_USERS\$SID_OF_USER\Environment` to set the variables there.

To get the SID of that user you can use this command:

```
wmic useraccount where name='username' get sid
```

Comment: nice! I suppose this also works for the domain users as well. Let me try this out